# Powershell to monitor a folder and send email when there are new files

Tags: powershell, shell

I need some assistance on how to create a powershell to monitor a folder and subfolders and send an email every 15 minutes for example, with a list of files that added to this folder

I will set up a schedule task to run every 15 minutes

Email output will be something like:

File Name, Path
TEST.TXT uploaded to C:\ROOT\BUSINESS
test2.txt uploaded to C:\ROOT\BUSINESS\May2021

Here is what I have so far. Any help is appreciated.

```
SMTPServer = "EMAIL SERVER (ip)"
$SMTPPort = "111"
$Username = "SENDER@EMAIL.COM"
$path="C:\ROOT\BUSINESS\"

$to = "test1@gmail.com"
$cc = "test2@gmail.com"
$subject = " New File available "
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.subject = $subject
$message.to.add($to)
$message.cc.add($cc)
$message.from = $username

$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
#$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential $Username;

If ($File = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where { $_.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-15) }){
$smtp.send($message)}
write-host "Mail Sent"
```

Thanks

Comment: what is NOT working as needed? you seem to have the email part done ... so what is the actual problem?

Comment: Not receiving any emails, and no errors on the powershell @Lee_Dailey

Comment: @Lee_Dailey   i keep getting prompt for email password

Comment: PLEASE change your title to show ONLY what the problem is. ///// why don't you provide the account name & password? also, why don't you use the simpler `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet?yes, it has been _deprecated_ ... but it still works AND it has  `-Credential` parameter.

Comment: Agree with @Lee_Dailey.  As a note, `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` also has been depreciated and it is what `Send-MailMessage` uses so same thing only easier to use from within Powershell

Answer (score 0):

Try this condition:
`if ((Get-ChildItem $Path | Where { $_.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-15) }).Count -ge 1){ <# do something #> }`

Comment: This is unnecessary.  PS already evaluates the statement `($File = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where { $_.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-15) })` as true if the collection `$File` is not empty.  The way the OP had it is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Daniel  i keep getting prompt for email password